# Does this refer to a file system?

Tags: filesystems, partition

Understaning the Linux Kernel says

[image]

Modern Operating Systems says

[image]

In the second figure, does each arrow pointed from "Disk partition" refer to a file system?

According to the first figure, each such arrow should refer to a block group, instead of a file system. A file system can contain multiple block groups, and a partition can contain at most file system.

Thanks.

Comment: A primary partition can contain a filesystem or multiple secondary partitions

Comment: "A file system can contain multiple block groups, and a partition can contain at most file system." A pretty bad expression, I think. A filesystem is a data structure, might be stored anywhere, it contains files (and directories, symlinks…). The most general definition, a partition is field of  a "partitioned disk" structure, and can be used to store any data. But in real life, "partitioned disk" is always stored on a physical disk or hardware RAID (or virtual disk image, if you're nitpicking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first figure shows an Ext2 partition.  This means a disk partition that stores an Ext2 filesystem.  It does *not* show the entire disk.  It also shows the layout of a block group.

The second figure shows the entire disk.  It also shows "a possible file-system layout".  This layout is different to the layout of Ext2.

---

A disk may be divided into several disk "partitions".  It may be divided according to a partition table stored at the start and/or end of the disk.  A disk partition may be used to store a "filesystem".

An Ext2 filesystem can contain multiple "block groups".

"A possible file-system layout" might be simpler, and not use block groups at all.  This second figure is such an example.

---

The simpler layout - not using block groups - was used by the very first UNIX filesystem.  This first filesystem was just called "FS".

In BSD 4.2 (1983), the Fast File System (FFS) used "cylinder groups", which look the same as block groups.   FFS is also called the Unix File System (UFS).  Versions of it were adopted widely outside BSD.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_File_System#History_and_evolution

You might look at a Ext2 or "FFS" filesystem and think it looks like multiple independent filesystems.  However, block groups are not independent.  The data blocks of a file can be placed in other block groups, if necessary.

The reason for block groups is to keep associated data close together, i.e. the file's "i-node" and its data blocks.  This can improve performance by reducing disk head movements.

FAT32 filesystems (and earlier FAT filesystems) are similar to the old "FS", in the sense that they do not use block groups.  The FAT layout is different in other ways, for example there are no "i-nodes".

Answer (score 6):

In the second figure, each arrow points to a partition.

Partitions can contain file systems, but don’t have to. The lower part of the second diagram shows a possible file system layout, as its title says. The partition it is blown up from in the diagram contains the file system.

As a general rule, you can’t take two similar-looking diagrams and assume they refer to the same thing, whether that’s from a single book or even more so from two different books.

Partitions can contain other things than file systems, and they can end up containing multiple file systems. For example, in the MBR scheme, an extended partition can contain multiple logical partitions. When using LVM, a partition can be used as a physical volume, in a volume group, and contain parts of one or more logical volumes.